# Resize youtube video in web view on orientation change

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, youtube, orientation

I have a web view that doesn't take up the full screen. I set it's url to a youtube video to play the video in the web view area. When I change orientation of the device the view resizes but the content doesn't. If I set the scales page to fit flag on the web view it changes orientation properly but there's always white space around the video on the right and bottom regardless of orientation.

How can I get the video to fill the web view, and resize with orientation change without the wasted padding. Alternatively how can I make the video play full screen like it does on iPhone (which would be a viable alternative for me, skipping over the layout issue)

Comment: I'm interested in this too. Did you solve your problem? How did you do that?

Comment: @ima747 Hi, i am facing the same problem.  Did you solved this? If "yes", please post the answer of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I read this tutorial and was able to solve the problem.
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-elastic-videos

basically you can set the size of the containing item to one thing for portrait and another for landscape.

Also set your object embed code to have a height width of 100% instead of a fixed width.

This is my html:

```
<span class="youtube">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="ytPlayer" style="visibility: visible;" allowscriptaccess="always">
    </object>
</span>
```

This is my javascript:

```
var ytswf = document.getElementById('ytPlayer');
var videoID = 'Nky9omXFZD4';
ytswf.outerHTML = "<object height=\"100%\" width=\"100%\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" data=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID + "&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayerObj&amp;rel=0&amp;fs=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;egm=0\" id=\"ytPlayer\" style=\"visibility: visible;\" ><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"True\" /><param name=\"allowScriptAccess\" value=\"always\" /></object>";
```

This is my css:

```
.youtube{width:432px; height:245px;}
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait)
{
   .youtube{width:702px; height:398px;}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution a little more please? when your js is called?

Comment: Why you css does not contain style for landscape?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code and it works for me

```
    // css
    // You can add your own width and height values or insert this values using stringWithFormat
    NSString *css = @"<style type=\"text/css\">\
    .youtube{width:320px; height:363px;}\
    @media only screen and (orientation:portrait) { \
    .youtube{width:320px; height:363px;}\
    }\
    \
    @media only screen and (orientation:landscape) {\
    .youtube{width:480px; height:203px;}\
    }\
    </style>\
    ";

    // different format of urls for iOS 5 and iOS 6
    NSString *src = ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"6" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
    ? @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@?autoplay=1"        //  iOS  5
    : @"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@?autoplay=1";             //  iOS  6

    // inserting css in <head> and inserting src
    NSString *youTubeVideoHTML =  [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                   (@"<html><head>%@</head>\
                                    <body style=\"margin:0\">\
                                    <embed class=\"youtube\" id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
                                    ></embed>\
                                    </body></html>") , css , src  ];
    // setting YouTube video ID
    finalHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat: youTubeVideoHTML , videoID ];

    [self.webView loadHTMLString:finalHtml baseURL:nil];
```